# Can Karma use Visual Studio Reference Paths

Tags: karma-jasmine

I already have unit tests that run fine in Visual Studio via Resharper.  With Resharper, I use the reference path syntax at the beginning of the file to pull in dependencies.  Can Karma be configured to do the same thing?